# img element srounded by an anchor is doing a post back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, postback

i know a "hack" to avoid a post back by making a jquery bind click event to span that wraps 
the `img` element
though this time i need to have a herf for seo purpose 
this one is not working for me it is ither disabled if i add a jquery code with `return false`
or it does a post back .

```
<a id="a_ContactUs" href="contactUs.aspx">
    <span>
        <img class="img_ContatUs_CssClss" src="images/HebContactUs_RCL.png" alt="contact us" title="click here" />
    </span>
</a>
```

what is the right way to get around that post back issue 
and still use an anchor .

Comment: Did you notice the missing " after `a_ContactUs` in your a tag?

Comment: @Silox just here , thanks though, not the real problem as my code did not have that syntax error

Comment: Could you post your relevant js/jquery code? Im not sure to understand your problem.

Comment: @roasted i got it mate, thanks to your comment,  i just notesed  ... i did have a `return false` for the post back but did not take an action to redirect to contact.aspx in same function, i will post my full code if it matters (: problem solved though ,thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(' imgID or class here ').bind('click', function (e) {
    animatePageHide(e.target.id.split('_')[1] + ".aspx"); return false;
    // i have used the id as the page name... say contact.aspx the id of the element to bind
    // should be id="img_contact", then the split of the id returns the array that i take 
    // the array-element No1 which is 
   /*
   e.target.id[0] --> img
   e.target.id[1] --> contact
   then i concatenated the suffix ".aspx" thats it
   */
});
```

then a function to avoid a "disturbing to the eyes" Page refresh while redirecting:

```
function animatePageHide(pageURLRedirect2) {
    $("#DivNew_Main").fadeOut(500, function () {
         if (pageURLRedircet2 != undefined) window.location.href = pageURLRediret2 ;
    else window.location.href = "default.aspx";
    });

}
```